# There exists a positive real number $u$ such that $u^3 = 3$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

> Modify the Theorem that states *There exists a positive real number x such that $x^2  = 2$*.
>
> Show that there exists a positive real number $u$ such that  $u^3  = 3$.

So far, I have come up with the following but I am getting stuck:

Let  $S = \{ x  \geq  0 |  x^3 \leq  3\}$. Note that  $1 \geq 0$  and  $1^3 = 1 \leq 3$. So $ 1 \in S$. So  $S \neq \emptyset$. Therefore,  $\forall x \in S, x < 3$. So $S$ is bounded above. So, by the completeness axiom, $S$ has a supremum. Say $u = \sup S$. Suppose by way of contradiction  $u^3 \neq 3$. Then either  $u^3 < 3$  or  $u^3 > 3$.

Comment: You want to prove that there exists $u\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $u^3=2$ or $u^3=3$?

Comment: Your "therefore" is misplaced.

Comment: See my question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3436424/472818

Answer (score 1):

Now if $u^3 \lt 3$, find a real $v \gt u$ such that $v^3 \lt 3$  Then $u$ is not the sup, contradiction.  The other way is similar.